# Cannot make boolean global in Python

Tags: python, global-variables, local

I am very new to programming and am creating a function that takes a letter or letters and checks to see if it is within a word. I need to control the number of guesses so I would like to set a boolean to test whether it was correct. To be clear, I have looked through many other answers on this type of question but cannot figure out what is going on in this case.

I cannot seem to make the bool 'correct' return True even if the if statement is true. After looking this up it seems that making it a global variable should fix this, but it is not working for me. It's still returning False. 
How do I fix this? I am using Python 2.5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

```
randomWord = choose_word(wordlist)
guessedLetters = []   
correct = False
def userGuesses(letters):       
    newLetters = list(letters)          

    global correct      #change correct to global

    for i in range(len(letters)):   
        curLetter = letters[i]

        for j in range(len(randomWord)):    

            if curLetter == randomWord[j]: 
                guessedLetters[j] = randomWord[j]
                correct = True              

            else: 


                correct = False



    return guessedLetters
```

Comment: When you say it return false, I'm questioning if you are showing us all your code or you are lying saying it's returning `False`. Because what is `randomWord` it's not defined when you used it.

Comment: First off, you have two "return" statements. The second will never be working.

Comment: Stop using a global variable

Answer (score 0):

Some issues in the code:

- `randomWord` seems to be undefined.
- `guessedLetters` seems to be undefined as well.
- There are 2 returns in the function

If your code did run then maybe it never gets into the inner loop. Add some `print` statements at different places to see if the code at that point gets run.

Also note that you don't need to do `for j in range(len(letters))` just to access `letters[i]` later on. Just do:

```
for letter in letters:
    # your code
```

It's shorter and has the same effect. The same for the inner loop.

Good luck!

Editted: try to print out `randomWord` before entering the function to see what the value of that variable is.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally didn't paste those variables in. I added them in now. Thanks for the info! It does seem to run properly all the way through though. Everything seems to work properly except for that statement.